# Constrain a string parameter to be a constant from a specific class

Tags: c#, string, parameters, parameter-passing, constants

This is probably an incredibly dumb question but: I have a function that takes in a string, and I want to make sure that the string is a constant from a specific class. Essentially the effect I'm looking for is what enums do:

```
enum MyEnum {...}
void doStuff(MyEnum constValue) {...}
```

Except with strings:

```
static class MyFakeStringEnum {
    public const string Value1 = "value1";
    public const string Value2 = "value2";
}
// Ideally:
void doStuff(MyFakeStringEnum constValue) {...}
// Reality:
void doStuff(string constValue) {...}
```

I know this can technically be achieved by doing some thing like

```
public static class MyFakeStringEnum {
    public struct StringEnumValue {
        public string Value { get; private set; }
        public StringEnumValue(string v) { Value = v; }
    }
    public static readonly StringEnumValue Value1 = new StringEnumValue("value1");
    public static readonly StringEnumValue Value2 = new StringEnumValue("value2");
}
void doStuff(MyFakeStringEnum.StringEnumValue constValue) {...}
```

But it feels kind of overkill to make an object for just storing one single value.

Is this something doable without the extra code layer and overhead?

**Edit**: While a enum can indeed be used for a string, I'd like to avoid it for several reasons:

- The string values may not always be a 1:1 translation from the enum. If I have a space in there, different capitalization, a different character set/language, etc. I'd have to transform the enum in every function where I want to use it. It might not be a lot of overhead or a performance hit in any way, but it still should be avoided--especially when it means that I'm always mutating something that should be constant.
- Even if I use a separate string array map to solve the above function, I would still have to access the translations instead of just being able to use the enum directly. A map would also mean having two sources for the same data.
- I'm interested in this concept for different data types, ex. floats, ulongs, etc. that cannot be easily represented by enum names or stored as an enum value.

As for string -> enum, the point of using an enum in the first place for me is that I can rely on intellisense to give me a constant that exists; I don't want to wait until compile time or runtime to find out. Passing in an actual string would be duck typing and that's something I definitely don't want to do in a strongly typed language.

Comment: Creating one class with comprehensible name and explicitly telling consumer of your method which values should be used - is not overhead.

Comment: You can already use the enum values' names as strings. What more do you need? Anyway, an enum doesn't truly constrain the method to only accept defined values; you can always pass in an instance of the enum's backing type cast to the enum type even if that value isn't defined in the enum.

Comment: If you need a way to "map" a Enum to a string representation (like you have to do in Internationlisation), a simple string array would do. At their Core Enums are just grouped integer constants, starting with 0.

Comment: Why not just use an enum? What benefit are you getting from using a string?

Comment: Something like TypeScript's "string literal types" would be nice in C#. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create an enum and parse the string value into an enum member. 
You can use the [Enum.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx) method to do that. It throws ArgumentException if the provided value is not a valid member.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    enum MyEnum
    {
        FirstValue,
        SecondValue,
        ThirdValue,
        FourthValue
    }

    public static void doStuff(string constValue)
    {
        var parsedValue = Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), constValue);

        Console.WriteLine($"Type: { parsedValue.GetType() }, value: { parsedValue }");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        doStuff("FirstValue");      // Runs 
        doStuff("FirstValuesss");   // Throws ArgumentException
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not Enum.TryParse? I think I have read that using exceptions to test validity does create overhead. Exceptions are for the unexpected not the expected.

Comment: You have right. TryParse would be better to the original question. Anyway, it does not matter because the question has been changed.